# Can a 16 year old student pilot "pre-take" the checkride?

Tags: faa-regulations, student-pilot, checkride

I am a student pilot, and I soloed about one month after my 16th birthday. I know I can't become a private pilot until I am 17, but I'm wondering if there is a way to take the check ride before you are 17, but be limited to the privileges of a student pilot until you are 17, at which point you can exercise the privileges of a private pilot? I doubt it, but its worth asking. I feel like I am pretty much ready to take the check ride, but I have to wait 8 more months. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

14 CFR Part 61.39 (a)(5) states that you can not take a checkride in the US until you are of age to hold the desired certificate.

> (5) Meet the prescribed age requirement of this part for the issuance of the certificate or rating sought;

Sorry. I encourage you to take as many mock-checkrides as possible in the meantime.

Also, in addition to mock-checkrides. You can train for your instrument rating. 14 CFR Part 61.65 allows you to take a combined checkride or even back-to-back private and instrument checkrides.

§61.65 Instrument rating requirements.
(a) General. A person who applies for an instrument rating must:

(1) Hold at least a current private pilot certificate, or be concurrently applying for a private pilot certificate, with an airplane, helicopter, or powered-lift rating appropriate to the instrument rating sought;

Comment: thank you so much for your response @DeanF. That is really helpful, I never considered the possibility of combining private and instrument training. How would that work, because don't you need a minimum of 50 hours of cross-country flight as a private pilot in addition to the required instrument training in order to take the instrument check ride?

Comment: @GeckoFox1001 - 14 CFR Part 61.65 (g) goes on to say    
(g) An applicant for a combined private pilot certificate with an instrument rating may satisfy the cross-country flight time requirements of this section by crediting:

(1) For an instrument-airplane rating or an instrument-powered-lift rating, up to 45 hours of cross-country flight time performing the duties of pilot in command with an authorized instructor; or

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, 45 of the required 50 hours of cross country pic time can be fulfilled by dual training that is not cross country? Since I already have around 45 hours of dual training and 5 hours of solo cross country, does that mean all I have to do is take the instrument written and do 40 hours of instrument training to take the combined checkride?

Comment: @GeckoFox1001 No, those 45 hours have to be dual xc. And talk with someone who has done a combined check ride before you consider going down that road.

Comment: @GeckoFox1001 - 61,65(g) only allows you to substitute an hour of dual cross country flight time performing the duties of PIC while not a certificated pilot for each hour of cross-country PIC flight time when certificate up to 45 hours.